"ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre" when running a Flutter project
When I run a Flutter project, I get this error:

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of your Java installation.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

When I check that path, there isn't even a file called jre.
I have reinstalled JDK, SDK, Android Studio, and the problem is still there.
My JAVA_HOME in system variables Variable: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\.
My path in user variables: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin.
